# Third-order susceptibilities of metals?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, material-science, metals, non-linear-optics

Can anyone point me to a source for measurements of the third-order nonlinear electric susceptibilities $\chi^{(3)}$ of various metals? Specifically in relation to the AC Kerr effect, so measurements of the second-order index $n_2$ would do as well.

For example, Bloembergen published measurements in 1969 (Opt. Comm. 1(4), 195) of the $\chi^{(3)}$ of silver and gold determined using THG, but I'd like to know if there's any data for other metals, and whether they are any different when studying the Kerr effect.

Comment: What frequency? (Or DC limit?)

Comment: Optical frequencies - visible and near infrared (say 500-1000 nm wavelengths.)

Comment: Do you want to measure the susceptibility of free standing foils or they can be mixed with other solvents.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Structural, linear and third-order nonlinear optical properties of Cu nanocrystal in sodium borosilicate glass](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921510713002225)

Comment: Cu nanocrystals embedded in glass, though, wouldn't be able to tell much about the solid metal, right?